# What is the most successful virus/rootkit?

Tags: virus

"Successful" is rated by infection rate.

Which virus/rootkit/malware has been able to infect the most computers globally?

Comment: http://wildammo.com/2010/10/12/10-most-destructive-computer-worms-and-viruses-ever/

Comment: Isn't that opinion-based?

Comment: Malware that combines all the infection techniques (compromising the BIOS/EFI, USB device's firmware, storage drive firmware, etc), compatible with all OSes (by providing multiple binaries for each OS), and is able to communicate with its peers via different methods (NFC, Bluetooth, WIFI, etc) without having a central server and that is able to repair itself if any of its components were removed (let's say the user updated their BIOS). A perfect, cold, evil creation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Conficker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conficker) was estimated to have 9 to 15 million concurrent infections at its peak. Mark Bowden does a good job telling its story in his book [Worm: The First Digital World War](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0802145949).

Other malware with high peak infections include [MyDoom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mydoom) with 1 million, [Storm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storm_Worm) with 1 to 10 million, and [Zeus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeus_%28malware%29) with 3.6 million in the US. For comparison, [Cryptolocker](http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-25506020) was in the news last year with a quarter million infections.